# How to remove whitespace in typeahed

Tags: flutter, dart, typeahead

I'm working on a typeahead search in flutter and let's say the user searches for `bengali biriyani` and return some names based on those two typed in words.

I'm splitting the search query like below:

```
List<String> searchWordList = search.toLowerCase().split(' ');
```

So List `searchWordList` is suppose to have `['Bengali','Biriyani']`. But once I typed in `bengali` and put in a space the list(I'm printing the list on every turn) becomes something like this:

```
['Bengali', ' ']
```

It gets fixed as soon as I start typing something else but this should not happen.

Here are the visual presentation of the problem:

[image: Types in the query]

[image: consoled output]

I'm guessing `split()` is not the way to go in this cases. But if so what can I do to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `trim()` to remove the extra whitespace:

```
List<String> searchWordList = search.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ');
```